# Javascript Int Argument Morphs at >= 000100

Tags: javascript, integer

Can anyone tell me why my numbers are changing unexpectedly after reaching 000100?

```
<script>
    function loadroute(id) {
        document.write(id+"<br>");

    }

      loadroute(000099); //99
      loadroute(000100); //64
      loadroute(000101); //65
      loadroute(101);    //101

</script>

99
64
65
101
```

https://jsfiddle.net/459aev7z/

Comment: They **starts with zero**.

Comment: [Javascript alert number starting with 0](//stackoverflow.com/q/12888075), [Javascript 0 in beginning of number](//stackoverflow.com/q/35047982) & [Javascript parseInt() with leading zeros](//stackoverflow.com/q/8763396)

Comment: @Tushar why `000099` is not octal number then

Comment: @Mahi because 9 does not exist in octal

Comment: @Noino so it will take `000099` as octal or decimal ??

Comment: @Mahi well, 9 does not exist in octal, so it won't be octal. It's impossible to read the number in that system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

console.log(010)

8;

If you start your number with a zero, javascript will understand is as a base8 number